# For some reason one polygon in a shapefile is hidden behind another. How to solve this?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, dissolve, splitting

In this photo, you can see that Great Brittain consists of two features. London and the rest.

[image: GB]

[image: Attribute table]

[image: Legend]

Problem is that London doesn't show as a separate colour. When I select great brittain, the area where London is supposed to be is also selected, but London in the attribute table is not. This shouldn't happen because I made this from a NUTS 1 map, where I gave London code 32 and the rest 31 and I dissolved on these numbers. And no, London is not in another layer.

However sometimes, when I zoom in and out quickly, when the rest of Great Brittain hasn't loaded yet, I see London:

[image: London]

Does anyone know how this happened and how to get London back, which seems to be behind GB for some reason?

Comment: Your dissolve has not worked as expected. I believe this may be "partially resolved" by using the advanced symbol levels in QGIS. On symbology navigate to Advanced > symbol levels > Enable symbol levels. You want London to be a higher number than the rest.

Comment: Problem is that these numbers are official IDs from an organisation. Is there a way to still display it as 32?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean I'm afraid and if it is a different question to the one asked then it should really be asked as another question. If you feel it is part of this question then I suggest you edit your question to clearly explain what you mean. Cheers

Comment: I'm refering to "you want London to be a higher number from the rest". Does this mean I have to change it in the attribute table?

Comment: Nevermind, it worked without doing so. I now understand what you meant. Thank you.